# MATLAB figure shift plot horizontally

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure(not using the plot command) in which the xdata is stored as an array of cells(as opposed to a matrix).
What I want to do is shift the plot horizontally, which could be done by adding a constant value to each element of xdata or shift the x-axis without affecting the plot.

I am not able to do so, and would really appreciate any help. Btw, my knowledge of MATLAB is very limited.

This is what I tried, and I seem to be getting an error:
set(findobj('type', 'line', 'color', 'r',),'xdata', new)

where 'new' is another cell array of the same dimensions as 'xdata'. But I don't see why this results in the error: "conversion to double fromcell is not possible"

Comment: can you show which commands did you use?

Comment: I am supposed to design a QFT controller, for which I downloaded a user-made QFT toolbox. This, contained a predefined function 'plotbnds', which is similar to 'plot', but has the xdata, ydata stored as a cell array.
I really don't know much about what the function does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the reason why `get(findobj('type', 'line', 'color', 'r',),'xdata')` returns a cell array is that there are multiple red-colored lines in your figure. If you clicked on the white arrow icon in the figure menu, selected one of the lines, and called `get(gco,'xdata')`, you'd see that the `xdata`-property of each individual line is still the normal numeric array.

In order to set the properties for a list of graphical objects, you need to put `xdata` into curly brackets (see the [documentation of the `set` command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html)):

```
 horizontalShift = 100;
 old = get(findobj('type', 'line', 'color', 'r',),'xdata');
 new = cellfun(@(x)x+horizontalShift,old,'UniformOutput',false);

 set(findobj('type', 'line', 'color', 'r',),{'xdata'}, new)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'll try that and see how it goes.
So the only thing I'm missing are the curly brackets? (I've already created a 'new' cell array of the same dimensions, containing the required shifted data points. So, I assume I don't need to use the 'cellfun' command?)